# Running an alter table alter column statement more than once in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Are there any negative implications to running an alter table alter column statement more than once in SQL Server?

Say I alter a column's datatype and nullability like this:

```
--create table
create table Table1 
(
    Column1 varchar(50) not null
) 
go

--insert some records
insert into Table1 values('a')
insert into Table1 values('b')
go

--alter once
alter table Table1 
    alter column Column1 nvarchar(250) not null
go

--alter twice
alter table Table1 
    alter column Column1 nvarchar(250) not null
go
```

The above set of sql all works and I have tested these. I could also test for the properties in the alter statements. The question is that is there any advantage to say checking if the column is not already nullable before altering.

After the first alter, does SQL Server figure out that the table has already been altered and hence the 2nd alter essentially does nothing?

Are there any differences across different versions of SQL Server about how this is handled?

Thanks,
Ilias

Comment: Did you try it? What happens? Also, you can check to see if your column exists before hand, or check the other properties and conditionally perform the alter statements.

Comment: I can't think of any differences. Your statements are self-contained in their own BATCH as it must be (i.e. `GO` statements). For instance, try to add a column and reference it in the same batch. It will error out.

Comment: @Jeremy I have tried and works as expected, I have edited the question to hopefully make it clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a metadata only operation.

It doesn't have to read or write any of the data pages belonging to `Table1`. It isn't quite a no-op though.

It will still start up a transaction, acquire a schema modification lock on the table and update the `modified` column in the row for this table in `sys.sysschobjs` (exposed to us through the `modified_date` column in `sys.objects`).

Moreover because the table has been modified any execution plans referencing the table will need to be recompiled on next usage.